# Git error : The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

When I am typing the following command:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/biodoop-seal/code biodoop-seal-code
```

I am getting the error below:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: did you have a look on the questions already existing here and could you confirm that your problem is totally different from them? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+remote+end+hung+up+unexpectedly

Comment: `git clone` has a `--verbose` parameter. Try `git clone --verbose git://git.code.sf.net/p/biodoop-seal/code biodoop-seal-code` and post the full output here

Comment: i saw a couple of posts quite similar to mine but no, the error is not fixed by their suggested solutions..:(

Comment: even with verbose, exactly the same output is showing. i am beginning to doubt if the remote repository even exists.

Comment: you did confirm that the project biodoop-seal does really exist, did you?